# Nginx to split web traffic to a blog hosted on my domain

Tags: nginx, routing, rewrite, reverse-proxy, url

At the moment, I am using an Nginx frontend to cache static content for my DotNetNuke based website hosted at the hypotetical address www.mydomain.com, along with some other tasks.

In this era of inbound marketing, I am thinking about hosting a blog or some other kind of article database with relevant content, but I want to have the blog hosted on my main domain, not a sub domain.

So, can i use Nginx to forward all traffic from www.mydomain.com/blog/* to a separate web application (possibly wordpress), while still send all other traffic to www.mydomain.com/* except for the /blog/* folder to DNN like before?

And would google and other search engines then completely accept and index the wordpress articles as pages at the main url along with the dnn stuff?

Edit:
Since SEO is my main objective with this, is there antall gotchas with regards to getting the optimal http response codes for the content pages?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with an nginx reverse proxy. It's the same idea of using `/app1` and `/app2` going to different backends. Take a look at some nginx tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reverse proxy feature along with an ip and port to point the server at another address.

```
server{
    listen    80;
    location /blog/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:81;
    }
}

server {
    listen    81;
    location / {
        root   /sites/blog/;
    }
}
```

http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/